a Cauchy Schwarz application
Here an inequality that I feel that CS may prove it but I can't find the right way to use it :
$\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right )^{2}+\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}\right )^{2}\leqslant \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_{i}^{2}+b_{i}^{2}}  \right )^{2}$
Thank you for your time
here's where I stuck after developping all I have :
$\sum_{i\neq j}a_ia_j+b_ib_j\leq \sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{a_i^{2}+b_i^{2}}\sqrt{a_j^{2}+b_j^{2}}$

It is “Schwarz” and not “Schwartz” – Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz

ty for noticing it I edited it  !

Define $x_i^2 = a_i^2+b_i^2, x_i >0$, then Using Multinomial theorem, $$ \left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\right)^2=\sum_{ \substack{ 0 \le j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n \le 2\\ j_1+j_2+\cdots +j_n = 2}} \frac{2}{j_{1}!j_{2}!\cdots j_{n}!} x_1^{j_1} x_2^{j_2} \cdots x_k^{j_k} \\ =2\sum_{ \substack{0 \le j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n \leq 1\\ j_1+j_2+\cdots +j_n = 2}}  x_1^{j_1} x_2^{j_2} \cdots x_k^{j_k} + \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2    =2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^n x_i x_j + \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 $$
Now using the inequality you have developed, ($x_ix_j \ge a_ia_j+b_ib_j$) $$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 \ge 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^n (a_ia_j+b_i b_j) + \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2+\left( \sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^2 $$

hello ty for your answer I don't get how you get the right answer, where the square root go ?

It is hidden in the definition of $x_i$, $x_i = \sqrt{a_i^2+b_i^2}$.
